# Cuda Dynamic Parallelism and Recursion Performance

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I am really curious about the performance of dynamic parallelism and the recursion abillity that gives you. So i make a simple benchmark of a cpu recursion and a device(gpu) recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

__global__ void recurse(int level)
{
    if (level<0)
    {
        return;
    }
    level--;
    recurse<<<1,1>>>(level);
    recurse<<<1,1>>>(level);
    return;
}

void serial_recurse(int level)
{
    if (level<0)
    {
        return;
    }
    level--;
    serial_recurse(level);
    serial_recurse(level);
    return;

}


int main()
{
    struct timeval startwtime,endwtime;
    double seq_time;

    printf("Startin here\n");

    int level_1 = 22;
    gettimeofday(&startwtime,NULL);

    serial_recurse(level_1);

    gettimeofday(&endwtime,NULL);

    seq_time = (double)((endwtime.tv_usec - startwtime.tv_usec)/1.0e6+endwtime.tv_sec - startwtime.tv_sec);
    printf("serial time = %f \n", seq_time);

    int level=22;
    
    gettimeofday(&startwtime,NULL);

    recurse<<<1,1>>>(level);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    gettimeofday(&endwtime,NULL);

    seq_time = (double)((endwtime.tv_usec - startwtime.tv_usec)/1.0e6+endwtime.tv_sec - startwtime.tv_sec);
    printf("parralel time = %f \n", seq_time);

    return 0;
}
```

The result was really disappointing for the dynamic parallelism:
cpu: 0.04666500  sec 
gpu: 283.620204  sec

Is there any way to have a better performance with dynamic parallelism or it's still too soon?

Comment: Your GPU case ends up doing something like 2^22 kernel launches.  Each kernel launch has some overhead, on the order of a few microseconds at least, and they cannot all run in parallel.  (Do the math?)  If you compare a kernel launch to a single CPU function call of an empty function, that will never be interesting.  Furthermore, you are issuing zero parallel work at each recursion.  The GPU is generally uninteresting if you have no parallel work to perform per kernel launch.  So, no I wouldn't suggest this programming pattern on the GPU and I wouldn't expect this case to improve in the future

Comment: If a use a __device__ function to avoid the overhead of the kernel launch will i have a better performance?Or it's a wrong approach. I am trying to understand the utility of the dynamic parallelism so i could achieve good performance in algorithms like constructing a tree.

Comment: Yes, you would have better performance (why not try it and find out?).  You may have to make some special provisions for the GPU thread stack to accommodate this large level of recursion.    It still isn't going to compare favorably to the CPU case because you would still be ultimately testing **single-threaded** behavior of a single CPU thread vs. a single GPU thread, and that isn't going to be a favorable comparison.  The GPU doesn't provide interesting performance for that case/comparison.  But I would expect performance to be better than your code in the question.

Comment: AFAIK most recursive algorithms can be realized in a non-recursive way, and that may end up being a better realization for the GPU, from the standpoint of stack utilization, especially when you expect the possibility of a large recursion depth.

Comment: Yeah, you are right! Definitely better than my code in the question but i don't think it is a good approach either. As you said it's one gpu thread vs one cpu thread. I guess the only way a gpu recursive approach to be favorable over a cpu one is to overtake it because of the parallel work doing in each recursion, as you said in your first answer. Thank you very much.